# Android: If I have a new phone and I restore an app from an old phone, will background tasks still run if I don't launch the app?

Tags: android, device, restore

If I restore an app from my old Android phone to my new Android phone and I don't launch it, will I still be able to get `push notifications`, receive `broadcasts` etc. for that app?

I know if you install an app from play store you and don't launch it you won't be able to but what about from a device restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did some testing and the answer is no. If you do not launch the app your code will not run even if you installed the app via device restore.